# Why does Omniknight have 62 shovels?

Tags: dota-2

The ESL One Birmingham Dota 2 tournament is now underway, and while watching some of the games I noticed new icons above the usual hero abilities in-game.

Specifically, there's a row of 6 new icons or buttons above each hero's QWER skills. The first four icons have numbers next to them which seem to vary from hero to hero. Here's an example I took from a [recent game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_r3-Nc-X4o):

[image]

**What are all of these new icons and what do they mean?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are consumable items and actions available with purchase of [The International Battlepass 2019](http://www.dota2.com/international/battlepass).
From left to right, they are:

- Trusty Shovel, used to dig up treasures such as Battle Points or the "cosmically-rare" Honey Heist Baby Roshan courier.
- Silly Monkey, which cheers for the player's last hits and denies, and flings poo at enemy heroes attacking the player (purely cosmetic).
- War Drums, which plays a sound when attacked. Note that this item can currently activate on-hit effects such as Templar Assassin's Psi Blades spilling, and Enigma's Eidolon's multiplication, so it is usually banned in tournaments.
- Snake Balloon, which floats around and bounces away from heroes.
- High Five; exactly what it sounds like. Can be used with allies or enemies.
- Avatar Banner, which plants a banner with an image of the player's hero or Steam avatar.